# Copy multiple files with bash script from command line arguments?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, terminal

I want to create a script that allows me to enter multiple filenames from the command line, and have the script copy those files to another directory. This is what I am trying but I keep getting an error of

line 10: binary operator expected

```
#!/bin/bash

DIRECTORY=/.test_files
FILE=$*
if [ -e $DIRECTORY/$FILE ]; then
        echo "File already exists"
else
        cp $FILE $DIRECTORY
fi
```

So if the script was named copfiles.sh, I am writing...

```
./copyfiles.sh doc1.txt doc2.txt
```

It will move the files, but if they already exist, it won't read the error message.

Also I get the "line 10: binary operator expected" error regardless of it the files are there or not. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Create a new script that contains just `FILE=$*` and `echo "[ -e $DIRECTORY/$FILE ]"` and see what it gets you when you run it with those arguments. Then see if that error makes more sense (and think about how you need to properly test for multiple files in the target directory.

Comment: A good debugging tip for Bash is to add the line `set -x` That will cause bash to print each line before it executes it.  That way you'll be able to see how variables are expanding and what exactly each line looks like before it is executed.

Comment: @EtanReisner I get
     [ -e /test.doc ]
 I made the script name stack.sh, and ran ./stack.sh test.doc

Comment: That's not what you ran originally. Using two arguments would have shown you the issue. Which is why I said "run it with those arguments".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a possible problem, if you had a filename with a space or had multiple arguments $* would have spaces in it so `[ -e $DIR/$FILE ]` will expand to have lots of words, like `[ -e /.test_files/First word and more ]` and `-e` expects just 1 word after it.  Try putting it in quotes like

```
if [ -e "$DIRECTORY/$FILE" ]
```

Of course, you may only want to store $1 in $FILE to get just the first argument.

To test all the arguments you want to loop over the arguments and test each with something like

```
for FILE in "$@"; do
    if [ -e "$DIRECTORY/$FILE" ]; then
        echo "$FILE already exists"
    else
        cp "$FILE" $DIRECTORY
    fi
done
```

Using quotes around $@ to preserve spaces in the original arguments as well

Comment: Ohhh okay, so basically since $DIRECTORY and $FILE are two different arguments essentially, the -e will not recognize them as a single pathname without the quotes?

Comment: $DIRECTORY and $FILE are different variables, with $FILE containing all of the arguments to your scrip.  When `-e` tries to do its check it will separate everything that comes after it on spaces (well, really the contents of $IFS, but usually white space).  If $FILE contains spaces that will make `-e` think you're passing multiple arguments to it, but if you put quotes around it `-e` will know to treat everything as a single argument.  I haven't tried it but if you use `[[ ... ]]]` instead of `[ ... ]` with double brackets it might be smarter.

Comment: Okay I get what you are saying. The only problem I have no is "File already exists" error will only occur when I run the script with one argument. If I run it with multiple arguments, and one or more of the files are in the other location, the error message won't occur, it will just act as if it copied the files over.

Comment: Right, you'd have to do a separate `-e` test for each argument if you want it to have lots of arguments.  You want to loop over the variables of $*, not try to do it in a single step with just one `-e` for them all

Comment: Okay, I will work at figuring that out. Thanks so much!

edit: got it to work!